# How to prove that existence of one-way functions implies P≠NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, cryptography, p-vs-np, one-way-functions

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=One-way_function&oldid=1019270544):

> The existence of such one-way functions... would prove that the complexity classes P and NP are not equal.

How is this proved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that P=NP, and that $f\colon \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^*$ is an arbitrary function computable in polynomial time. Suppose that $|x| = n$, and we are given $y = f(x)$. We will show how to find $z \in \{0,1\}^n$ such that $y = f(z)$ in polynomial time (in $n$).

Using an NP oracle, we determine whether there exists $z$ such that $z_1 = 1$ and $y = f(z)$. If so, we set $w_1 = 1$, and otherwise, we set $w_1 = 0$. Using an NP oracle, we determine whether there exists $z$ such that $z_1 = w_1$, $z_2 = 1$, and $y = f(z)$. We set $w_2$ accordingly. Continuing in this way, we eventually found $z$ such that $y = f(z)$. Since we assumed that P=NP, this algorithm runs in polynomial time.

Comment: Is _NP oracle_ the same as polynomial-time NP-complete algorithm? Or what is it?

Comment: It's a machine that can solve NP problems. If P=NP, then you can simulate an NP oracle with a standard Turing machine.

Comment: What does the sub-index represent here?

Comment: The index represents individual bits.